In a Scala sbt project how can I see the test dependencies?
In a Scala sbt project I'm trying to see the dependencyTree for a sub-module. But when I run

sbt 'project sub-module' dependencyTree

I don't see all of my dependencies listed. e.g. In the build.sbt if I list
"com.my.project" %% "test-utils-lib" % "1.0.4" % IntegrationTest classifier "tests"
"com.my.project" % "configreader" % "1.1.1"

Here I can find the configreader in the dependency tree. But there are no references to the test-utils-lib. I assume this is because it's a test dependency? Is there a command to ensure it is listed?
For more context, the 1.0.4 version of the test-utils-lib has been deleted from artefactory. I've updated the build.sbt to use a newer version. e.g. 1.0.5. But I'm still hitting the exact same error in IntelliJ. i.e. Not Found version 1.0.4. I want to use the dependencyTree to find any implicit references to the old version. But then I hit the above.

Maybe try sbt submodule/Test/dependencyTree

Interesting command to be made aware of. But it did not work. I also tried sbt submodule/IntegrationTest/dependencyTree and got the same results. i.e. No test-utils-lib.

I was able to fix my Not Found error by adding "com.my.project" %% "test-utils-lib" % "1.0.5" % Test classifier "tests". But I'd still like to understand where the 1.0.4 reference is coming from.
